# Why does this custom shape take up the entire vertical space?

Tags: swiftui, shapes

I would like to know why this custom shape, which is just a letter template takes up the entire space of the view?? I never drew a line that required that much vertical space so I'm wondering what is going on.

Here is an example of what it looks like.

[image]

You can see that the image is pretty much doubled vertically.

Here is the code of the shape with its Parent View

```
 import SwiftUI
    
    struct ParentView: View {
       var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Spacer()
           LetterPreviewShape()
       }
    }

}


    struct LetterPreviewShape: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let startingPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY)
            let paragraphStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.1, y: rect.maxY * 0.1)
            
            var path = Path()
            
            //Letter outline
            path.move(to: startingPoint)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
            path.closeSubpath()
            
            //Greeting Line
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.1, y: rect.maxY * 0.07))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.3, y: rect.maxY * 0.07))
            
            
            //Body Strokes
            path.move(to: paragraphStartingPoint)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.9, y: rect.maxY * 0.1))
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.1, y: rect.maxY * 0.11))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.9, y: rect.maxY * 0.11))
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.1, y: rect.maxY * 0.12))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.9, y: rect.maxY * 0.12))
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.1, y: rect.maxY * 0.13))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.9, y: rect.maxY * 0.13))
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.1, y: rect.maxY * 0.14))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.9, y: rect.maxY * 0.14))
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.1, y: rect.maxY * 0.15))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.9, y: rect.maxY * 0.15))
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.1, y: rect.maxY * 0.16))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.9, y: rect.maxY * 0.16))
            
           //Signature Line
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.7, y: rect.maxY * 0.18))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.9, y: rect.maxY * 0.18))
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.7, y: rect.maxY * 0.19))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.9, y: rect.maxY * 0.19))
            
            return path
        }
    }
```

Comment: It’s just like parent doesn’t decide the size of child views, it’s the child that decide what space it needs and gives it to the parent.So, basically when you declare VStack it gives all it’s available size to child views inside it, and child view based on it’s content decide how much space it needs, and send the detail to parent, and parent respects that.

Comment: this is very common in SwiftUI, all shape bace thing take all space! like @jnpdx answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shape does not have own frame, so you have to give it one externally (or it fills everything available), like

```
struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Spacer()
           LetterPreviewShape()
              .frame(height: 200)   // << this goes in `func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path`
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Shape`s in SwiftUI always fill the available space. It doesn't have anything to do with where you draw the content.

You can see this behavior replicated with the non-custom system shapes as well -- if you you just use a `Rectangle` or `Circle`, they will also fill the available space.

To constrain it, give it a `frame` -- possible in conjunction with a `GeometryReader` if you need to base it on the available size.

For example:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Spacer().frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2)
                Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```